# If $x_n\to x$ in $(X,d_X)$ and $f: (X,d_X)\to (Y,d_Y)$ is continuous then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $(Y,d_Y)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I have an exercise which I have completed and would like to check if my answer to it is correct, and if not, then I would like some feedback as to why not if possible.

Exercise: Show that if $x_n\to x$ in $(X,d_X)$ and $f: (X,d_X)\to (Y,d_Y)$ is continuous then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $(Y,d_Y)$. [Prove this using open sets rather than $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s.]

My proof:

What we have given:

- $x_n\to x$ which is equivalent to saying that for every open set $U$ containing $x$, $\exists N$ such that $x_n\in U \forall n\geq N$.
- $f:(X,d_X)\to (Y,d_Y)$ being continuous is equivalent to saying that for every open set $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Now, take any open set $U\subset Y$ which contains $f(x)$. Hence $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ which is also open, therefore $\exists N$ such that $x_n\in f^{-1}(U) ,\forall n \geq N$. Hence $\exists N$ such that $f(x_n)\in U,\forall n\geq N$, which implies that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the proof is correct. I would only underline the following:

Hence $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ which is also open, therefore, since $x_n$ converges to $x$ and $f^{-1}(U)$ is (sequentially) open, then there $\exists N$ such that $x_n\in f^{-1}(U) ,\forall n \geq N$.

I would mention that you are using the definition of “open set” that is usually known as “sequentially open set” (that in metric spaces it is equivalent to the definition of open set, but this is no longer true in general topological spaces).